# Translate content product template used by plugin after ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Im loading a slider (plugin) with ajax (after document ready) which uses the following to wrap my products into an existing content product template from my theme:

```
                while ( $the_query->have_posts()  && $count < $max_prods  ) {
                    $the_query->the_post();
                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
                    $count++;
                }
```

Unfortunately the add to card buttons are not translated. Any idea how to initialize the woocommerce language file again during the ajax load event or do i miss something else?

This is the ajax part:

```
        <script>
        function plaFetchPage(id, titleElm, contentElm) {
            jQuery.ajax({   url:        "' . admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) . '?action=pla&page="+id+"&nonce=' . wp_create_nonce( 'pla-nonce' ) . '",
                async:      true,
                type:       "GET",
                timeout:    60000,
                beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                },
                success:    function( result, status, xhr ) {
                                var updates = JSON.parse( result );
                                jQuery( titleElm ).html( updates["title"] );
                                jQuery( contentElm ).html( updates["content"] );
                },
                error:      function( xhr, status, error ) {
                },
                complete:   function( xhr, status, newurl ) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        jQuery(document).trigger("resize");
                    },100);                     
                    if ( typeof( plaCustomFunction ) == "function" ) {
                        plaCustomFunction(id);
                    }
                }
            });
        };
        </script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The "admin-ajax" endpoint is part of the admin area, so the "dashboard" language form the user profile will be used.

In my case the default site language was german and my language set in my user profile dashboard was english. So the button texts where in english.